# MongoDB error "no reachable servers" with golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I just followed this tutorial on youtube(https://youtu.be/GwQ1hvuSNJA).
But I got an error "no reachable servers" after `go run main.go`
How can I figure it out? Should I change localhost to mongodb uri?
Below is source code.

```
var rnd *renderer.Render
var db *mgo.Database

const (
    hostName       string = "localhost"
    dbName         string = "demo_todo"
    collectionName string = "todo"
    port           string = ":3000"
)

func init() {
    rnd = renderer.New()
    sess, err := mgo.Dial(hostName)
    checkErr(err)
    sess.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    db = sess.DB(dbName)
}

func main() {
    stopChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(stopChan, os.Interrupt)

    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Get("/", homeHandler)

    r.Mount("/todo", todoHandlers())

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr:         port,
        Handler:      r,
        ReadTimeout:  60 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 60 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  60 * time.Second,
    }

    go func() {
        log.Println("Listening on port ", port)
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Printf("listen: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: As a side note, consider never using `go run` except for feeding the amusement about the fact this command exists. Use `go build`/`go install`, then run the resulting executable. Stock Go implementation is not a scripting language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a side note: [`github.com/globalsign/mgo`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo) has long gone unmaintained (over 4 years now). Do use the [official MongoDB Go driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo).

---

You may pass a MongoDB URI to [`mgo.Dial()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Dial), not just a host name. Parts you don't specify will use a default which doesn't match your actual values. So provide a full URI.

It has the syntax of:

> ```
> [mongodb://][user:pass@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...][/database][?options]
> ```
>
> For example, it may be as simple as:
>
> ```
> localhost
> ```
>
> Or more involved like:
>
> ```
> mongodb://myuser:mypass@localhost:40001,otherhost:40001/mydb
> ```
>
> If the port number is not provided for a server, it defaults to 27017.
>
> The username and password provided in the URL will be used to authenticate into the database named after the slash at the end of the host names, or into the "admin" database if none is provided. The authentication information will persist in sessions obtained through the New method as well.

So do it like this:

```
uri := fmt.Sprintf("mongodb://%s:%s/%s", hostName, port, dbName)
sess, err := mgo.Dial(uri)
```